# Read in Files and split them into two dataframes (Pyspark, spark-dataframe)

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am quite new to Pyspark (and Spark) and have a concrete task to solve that is currently beyond my knowledge :).

I have a bunch of files of the following structure:

'File_A.dtx':

```
## Animal
# Header Start
Name, Type, isMammal
# Body Start
Hasi, Rabbit, yes
Birdi, Bird, no
Cathi, Cat, yes
## House
# Header Start
Street, Number
# Body Start
Main Street, 32
Buchengasse, 11
```

'File_B.dtx':

```
## Animal
# Header Start
Name, Type, isMammal
# Body Start
Diddi, Dog, yes
Eli, Elephant, yes
## House
# Header Start
Street, Number
# Body Start
Strauchweg, 13
Igelallee, 22
```

My anticipated result are two dataframes as follows:

Animals:

```
| Filename   | Name    | Type     | isMammal    | 
| ---------- | ------- | -------- | ----------- | 
| File_A.dtx | Hasi    | Rabbit   | yes         | 
| File_A.dtx | Birdi   | Bird     | no          | 
| File_A.dtx | Cathi   | Cat      | yes         | 
| File_B.dtx | Diddi   | Dog      | yes         | 
| File_B.dtx | Eli     | Elephant | yes         |
```

House:

```
| Filename   | Street       | Number   | 
| ---------- | ------------ | -------- | 
| File_A.dtx | Main Street  | 32       | 
| File_A.dtx | Buchengasse  | 11       | 
| File_B.dtx | Strauchweg   | 13       | 
| File_B.dtx | Igelallee    | 22       |
```

The solution should be able to work in parallel. It can work per file since each file is small (around 3 MB) but I have a lot of them.

Thanks so much for hints.

What I currently have is just:

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
df1 = spark.read.text(filelist).withColumn("Filename", input_file_name())
```

Now my main problem is, how do I split the dataframe according to the rows `## Animal` and `## House` and aggregate it again to a dataframe to fullfil my task?

Comment: Finally, my question is complete ! Sorry for the multiple edits! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the format of the before hand and no two dataframes will have the same number of columns. Then you can do the following:

1. Remove comments (lines start with `#`) from the dataset
2. Remove header rows from the dataset
3. Remove empty lines
4. Split the lines using `,`
5. Create `animals_df` as subset of rows from df in step 4 wherein the size of array from splitting is equal to 3 and extract the array values as columns
6. Create `house_df` as subset of rows from df in step 4 wherein the size of array from splitting is equal to 2 and extract the array values as columns

```py
from  pyspark.sql.functions import element_at, input_file_name, length, col as c, split, size

filelist = ["File_A.dtx", "File_B.dtx"]

df1 = spark.read.text(filelist).withColumn("Filename", input_file_name())

# STEP 1
comment_removed = df1.filter(~(c("value").startswith("#")))

# STEP 2
header_removed = comment_removed.filter(~(c("value").isin("Name, Type, isMammal", "Street, Number")))

# STEP 3
remove_empty_lines = header_removed.filter(length("value") > 0)

# STEP 4
processed_df = remove_empty_lines.withColumn("value", split("value", ",")).withColumn("Filename", element_at(split("Filename", "/"), -1)).cache()

# STEP 5
animals_df = processed_df.filter(size("value") == 3).selectExpr("Filename", "value[0] as Name", "value[1] as Type", "value[2] as isMammal")
animals_df.show()

"""
+----------+-----+---------+--------+
|  Filename| Name|     Type|isMammal|
+----------+-----+---------+--------+
|File_A.dtx| Hasi|   Rabbit|     yes|
|File_A.dtx|Birdi|     Bird|      no|
|File_A.dtx|Cathi|      Cat|     yes|
|File_B.dtx|Diddi|      Dog|     yes|
|File_B.dtx|  Eli| Elephant|     yes|
+----------+-----+---------+--------+
"""

# STEP 6
house_df = processed_df.filter(size("value") == 2).selectExpr("Filename", "value[0] as Street", "cast(value[1] as int) as Number")
house_df.show()
"""
+----------+-----------+------+
|  Filename|     Street|Number|
+----------+-----------+------+
|File_A.dtx|Main Street|    32|
|File_A.dtx|Buchengasse|    11|
|File_B.dtx| Strauchweg|    13|
|File_B.dtx|  Igelallee|    22|
+----------+-----------+------+
"""
```

Comment: Thanks heaps... this is an excellent and nice introduction into the topic! Exactly as I needed it. For me, having worked with 'normal' dataframes only, it is harder than expected to get used to the new syntax and new handling!

Comment: You have now used the nice trick that the number of columns were different for the two types (animals and house)... However, would it be also possible to use the `## Animal` and `## House` tags directly?

Comment: If the files have line numbers or if you read the files as an RDD and add an index then, `## Animal` and `## House` can be used to identify range of rows containing the rows.